# "Vile language to be using." sentence structure?

Tags: sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

Full context:

> *Woman:* And you don't think maybe you should have asked her, seeing as how you f**k her every day after school?
> *Man:* **Vile language to be using.**
> *Woman:* Well, feel free to explain in your own words.

*Source: "Normal People" TV series, S1E3*

Please break down this sentence.
More specifically, what the `Noun to be Ving` construct is used for?

Comment: It's simply an abbreviated form of "What vile language to be using!" or perhaps "That's vile language to be using." In everyday speech such elisions are common: "Time to be going", "Dreadful place to be living!" "Crazy way to be talking!"

Answer (score 1):

It's called **Ellipsis** - when we leave out a word/words which are understood by context, but which would normally be expected if we were to adhere to strict grammar rules. It's often used in speech/colloquial English. [See here for more information and examples](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/ellipsis).

So, what are the missing words in your example?

> [That's] vile language to be using.